# jQuery hover() not working with absolutely positioned elements and animation

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

I have some html that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="move"><span class="text">add</span><span class="icon-arrow"></span></a>
```

And I have a jquery event registered on the anchor tag:

```
$('a.move').hover(
    function (event) {
        $(this).children('span.text').toggle();
        $(this).animate({right: '5px'}, 'fast');
    },
    function (event) {
        $(this).children('span.text').toggle();
        $(this).animate({right: '0px'}, 'fast');
    }
);
```

When I mouse over the anchor tag, it displays the span.text and moves the anchor 5px to the right.

Now, due to complications that I don't feel like getting into, I have to set position: relative; on the container and absolutely position the icon and the text so that the icon appears on the left and the text on the right.

THE PROBLEM:

When I mouse over the anchor tag, the icon moves right, and the mouse ends up over top of the text (which appears). Unfortunately, the 'out' function gets called if I move my mouse from the icon to the text and the animation starts looping like crazy. I don't understand what's causing the "out" event to fire, as the mouse is never leaving the anchor tag.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Instead of hover you can use the "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events, which do not fire when child elements get in the way:

```
$('a.move').bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
  $(this).children('span.text').toggle();
  $(this).animate({right: '5px'}, 'fast');
})
.bind('mouseleave', function (e) {
  $(this).children('span.text').toggle();
  $(this).animate({right: '0px'}, 'fast');
});
```

Comment: I have similar situation and this solution is not working for me in IE8. Any ideas/suggestions?